# Scrapy+Xpath+Python: Datapoint cannot be scraped

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, web-crawler

I want to scrape the URLs here:
[image]

I tried these:

```
response.xpath('//header[@class="geodir-entry-header"]/a/@href').extract()

response.xpath('//div[class="geodir-content "]/header/a/@href').extract()

response.xpath('//div[@class="geodir-content "]/header[@class="geodir-entry-header"]/a/@href').extract()
```

All returned an empty list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does

`response.xpath('//h3[@class="geodir-entry-title"]/a/@href').extract()`
or
`response.xpath('//header[@class="geodir-entry-header"]/h3/a/@href').extract()`

Work for you?

Looks like you just missed the `h3` tag which contains the `a` tags you need.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is just add h3 tag which you accidentally missed.

```
response.xpath('//header[@class="geodir-entry-header"]/h3/a/@href').extract()
```

& if you want to get only the first url then add

```
response.xpath('//header[@class="geodir-entry-header"]/h3/a/@href').extract_first()
```

or

```
response.xpath('//header[@class="geodir-entry-header"]/h3/a/@href').extract()[0]
```

Comment: @Debbie I think you get your answer!